# React Material UI Grid Horizontally Align Items for Containers With Different Number of Items

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I am using the React Material UI Grid System to align my elements on the page which uses flexboxes internally.

Everything works great but I cannot figure out how to horizontally align items when the containers contain a different number of items.

In the following [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-hofstadter-smzsd), I have 2 container items that take a width of 6 each. The first one contains items `x1` and `x2` and the second container contains the items `y1`, `y2` and `y3`. As you can see, the way it looks right now is a little bit odd. I want `x1` horizontally aligned with `y1` and the same goes for `x2` and `y2`.

The reason why I placed `x1`, `x2` in the first container and `y1`, `y2`, `y3` in the second container is because they semantically belong together. Thus, I can give the outer container different `xs`, `sm`, `md`, `lg`, `xl` values and if it hits the breakpoint, they will still show up in the correct order.

However, if I simply place them in 3 rows with 2 columns each, they will break in the order `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`, ... That would obviously not be right.

Therefore, my question is, how can I horizontally align them?

**Edit:**

This is how it looks right now:

[image]

This is how it want it to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to add props to the `<Grid>` to make this possible.

1. `alignItems="flex-start"` will allow grid items to stick to the top then fall towards the bottom.
2. `direction="column"` will change the flow of how items are "stacked" in a sense. This will change the sizing of the container and items that it is attached to so expect some `xs={12}` to turn into `xs={6}` and vice versa.

Here's the example code below as well as its implementation via sandbox.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Grid alignItems="flex-start" container spacing={1}>
        <Grid container direction="column" item xs={6} spacing={1}>
          <Grid item xs={12} style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}>
            x1
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}>
            x2
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container direction="column" item xs={6} spacing={1}>
          <Grid item xs={12} style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}>
            y1
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}>
            y2
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}>
            y3
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much.